# Objective-c: NSMutableDictionary setObject not working

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. When I try to check the dictionary either by a specific key or allkeys I either get an error or null. (I know I'm using a string where I could be using a boolean for the conditional I just like having a check like that say true or false instead of YES and NO. Add that to my OCD list. :D ) activePlayer is set in an awakeFromNib method to 1, it can be switched using a popupbutton between P1 and P2.

```
- (IBAction)setPlayer:(id)sender {

 haserror = @"false";
 errmsg = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];
 [errmsg retain];
 [errmsg appendString: @"There was a problem setting your team up\n\n"];
 thisTeamName = [txtTeamName stringValue];
 thisTeamColor = [pdTeamColor itemTitleAtIndex:[pdTeamColor indexOfSelectedItem]];

 //validate form
 if ([thisTeamName isEqualToString:@""]) {
  haserror = @"true";
  [errmsg appendString: @"You must enter a team name\n\n"];
 }

 if ([thisTeamColor isEqualToString:@"Select A Color"]) {
  haserror = @"true";
  [errmsg appendString: @"You must select a team color\n\n"];
 }

 //check for errors
 if (haserror == @"true")  {
  [self showAlert: errmsg];
 } else { 

  //set up treasury
  treasury = 1000;

  //convert to string for display
  [lblTreasury setStringValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%i", treasury] ];


  //add items to dictionary
  if (activePlayer == @"1") { 

   [p1TeamData setObject:thisTeamName forKey:@"teamName"];
   [p1TeamData setObject:thisTeamColor forKey:@"teamColor"];
   [p1TeamData setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", treasury] forKey:@"cash"];
  } else { 
   [p2TeamData setObject:thisTeamName forKey:@"teamName"];
   [p2TeamData setObject:thisTeamColor forKey:@"teamColor"];
   [p2TeamData setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", treasury] forKey:@"cash"];
  }

  NSLog(@"%@", [p1TeamData allKeys]);  

 }

 [errmsg release];
}
```

[Edit: here's the .h file]

```
@interface GameController :NSObject {

IBOutlet id btnSaveData;
IBOutlet id lblTreasury;
IBOutlet id pdPickPlayer;
IBOutlet id pdTeamColor;
IBOutlet id txtTeamName;

int activePlayer;
NSString* activePlayerName;
NSString* activePlayerTeamColor;
int  treasury;

NSMutableDictionary* p1TeamData;
NSMutableDictionary* p2TeamData;

NSArray* players;
NSArray* teamColors;
NSArray* unittypes;

NSString* thisTeamName;
NSString* thisTeamColor;

NSMutableString* errmsg;
NSString* haserror;
```

}

-(void) awakeFromNib; 
- (IBAction) getPlayer : (id)sender;
- (IBAction) setPlayer : (id)sender;
-(void) showAlert : (NSMutableString* ) m;
@end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you initialize the collections in the `-initXXX` method. If not, they will be assigned to `nil`.

```
-(id)initXXX:... {
   if ((self = [super initYYY:...])) {
     ...
     p1TeamData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     p2TeamData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     ...
   }
   return self;
}
```

---

If all you want are "true" and "false", just define them yourself. It's not a reason to use string instead of BOOL. In fact, Foundation already defined TRUE and FALSE besides YES and NO.

Also, please use an integer for `activePlayer`.

You should always compare NSString with `-isEqualToString:`, not `==`.

```
if ([haserror isEqualToString:@"true"])

...

if ([activePlayer isEqualToString:@"1"])
```

This should be the reason why `p1TeamData` is always nil, because `activePlayer == @"1"` is unreliable and there could be player-1 stuff assigned to `p2TeamData`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, though t/f is not my problem right now, any idea why my I can't add objects to the dict?

Comment: Thanks, but I had a log within the conditional to make sure I P1 or P2 was active and even when I was within the conditional for P1 it was getting null for the dict.

Comment: @Pruitlgoe: Have you initialized `p1TeamData` and `p2TeamData`?

Comment: Yes<p>Here's my .h file (I just changed activePlayer to an int)<p>

Comment: @Pruitlgoe: No, I mean in the `-initXXX` method in the `.m` file.

Comment: @KennyTM - dang, that might be it...LOL. Coming from a PHP/Javascript/AppleScript background I keep forgetting when I have to init something and when I don't. Let me give that a try...

Comment: @KennyTM - you rock, that was it. Why, if I have NSMutableDictionary* pd1TeamData in my .h file do I have to also initialize it in my .m? If I had used @property and @synthesize would that have taken care of it?

Comment: @Pruitlgoe: No and no. They have to be manually initialized, otherwise they are filled with `nil`.